# How can I create a dynamic html output textbox which updates itself in real time as new results are calculated on Google Apps Script server?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I think I roughly understand how I can hand over results from a server apps script to a html and I sucessfully created a "Hello world" output with the code below.

Next, I would like to have a real time output for the values calculated in the loop (`result`).
So every time the result is there, the html textbox should update in real time and the new value should be written one line below the value before (as it would be the case in the console).

I cannot get my head around how to achieve this.
Please could you give me some hints and code examples?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Best wishes,
Ben

**code.gs:**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mypage');
}
var test = "Hello World";

function loopSomething() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     doSometing(i);
  }
  return test;
} 

function doSometing(i){
  var result = i*i;
  console.log(result);
}
```

**mypage.html:**

```
<html>
    
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<textarea id="textbox" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  
<script>
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");

function calculate() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).loopSomething();
}

function callback(whatToWrite) {
  textbox.value = whatToWrite;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `const txtBox = document.getElementById('textbox'); txtBox.value += '\n'+result;`. If your result already arrives in `doSometing()`, all you have to do is get the textbox's currently value, add a new line to it (\n) and add the result to it.

Comment: How do I get the current value of `result` handed over in real time from code.gs to mypage.html? Do I have to create an additional function/loop which updates the textbox in the html file? Thanks!

Comment: Your can get real time result by polling. Perhaps with setInterval